# REST XML serialization of lists of abstract classes with "i:type" attribute - how to convert that to tag name?

Tags: wcf, rest, xml-serialization

I'm writing a REST WCF service with methods to retrieve a collection of resources and a single resource. My resources are classes based on a single abstract class. In my method to retrieve a collection I have:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(File)), ServiceKnownType(typeof(Text))]
List<ResourceBase> GetCollection();
```

and that produces XML that looks like this:

```
<ArrayOfResourceBase xmlns="..." xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ResourceBase i:type="Text">
    ...
    </ResourceBase>
    <ResourceBase i:type="File">
    ...
    </ResourceBase>
</ArrayOfResourceBase>
```

My single object method looks like this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}")]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(File)), ServiceKnownType(typeof(Text))]
ResourceBase Get(string id);
```

and produces XML like this:

```
<Text xmlns="..." xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
</Text>
```

Is there a way to get those two xml parts to look the same, that is either to get rid of "i:type" tags in ArrayOf... and convert them to tag name, or force them in the single object response?

Answer (score 0):

There may be several solutions here, but I can think of a few right away:

1. Change the custom DataContract name of the DataContract class ResourceBase to always be Text. Like so:

   [DataContract(Name="Text")]
   class ResourceBase
   {
      ...
   }
2. Plug in a DataContractSurrogate to special-case this type
3. Plug in a custom DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior that plugs in a custom DataContractSerializer child that special cases this type
4. Use XmlSerializer. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/06/12/customizing-the-xml-for-collections-with-xmlserializer-and-datacontractserializer.aspx).